# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "REFERENCES": syntax error - foreign key creating

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm trying to create a foreing key. After checking the manuals [1](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) and [2](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) out i wrote this:

```
db.execute("create table if not exists table1 (id integer PRIMARY KEY, somedata integer)")
db.execute("create table if not exists table2 (names text, REFERENCES maintable (id)")
```

and got this:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "REFERENCES": syntax error

What did i miss? How can i create the foreing key? 
Thank you.

sqlite_version is 3.7.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your second ligne is wrong it should be

```
db.execute("create table if not exists table2 (names text,my_id integer, FOREIGN KEY(my_id) REFERENCES maintable (id))")
```

as explained in http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_basics

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work too. Now i got "sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error"

Comment: you miss a parenthesis in the end

Comment: Indeed. Thank you, the problem is solved. I need to be more attentive.

Comment: can you tag my answer as your reponse?